# Why does the speaker use the indefinite article in 'This is the last time you are seeing A guy like this'?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Last night I was watching a movie and towards the end of the movie there was a dialogue which goes like this -- "This is the last time you are seeing **a**  guy like this."

The speaker was telling this about himself to a number of people. So the question is, if the speaker is specifically referring to himself then why is the noun *guy*  not preceded by *the* instead of *a*?

Comment: Sure it wasn't _The last time you gonna see a bad guy like this again, let me tell you._?

Comment: The guy whom he represents (in acting) is not known to others previously. From the grammatical point of view, the guy is a first-time referent.

Comment: @mahmud First-time referents are very often definite references. Consider *I disagree with the thesis written by Guya Jones*. *The thesis written by Guya Jones* is a first time referent that is at the same time immediately identifiable. Also, read any popular article on the Internet; about 2 out of 3 definite references will be "first mentions."

Comment: @Clare, Then we have to discuss the whole topic of Articles here. I know that all the first-time referents won't take an indefinite article. We are discussing here the use of the indefinite article in the context of 'first-time' use and 'previously unknowing' to the audience. See, one of the uses of the definite article is: with countable singular nouns which are known to the audience either by previous mentioning or by their commonly knowing meaning. As your example, a first time reader or listener has no difficulty to know what a "thesis" is and when the author is mentioned, it is specific.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the articles in English are not the specific and 'inspecific', but the definite and indefinite.

That is, *definiteness* and *specificity*  are two different properties of noun phrases. In English, the definite article marks a noun phrase as being *definite*. All the time, or perhaps  with very few exceptions, a definite noun phrase is also specific.

Meanwhile, the indefinite article marks a noun phrase as *indefinite*. However, an indefinite noun phrase can be either specific or non-specific. The usage of the indefinite noun phrase *a guy like this* to refer to a known or specified individual, such as oneself, is an example of an indefinite, specific noun phrase. An example of an indefinite, non-specific noun phrase is *a guy from Canada* in *I want to marry a guy from Canada* (as in 'any guy from Canada'). But the same noun phrase is indefinite, specific in *I married a guy from Canada*.

Comment: Accepted though. But in one of the sites of articles it mentions, " Use indefinite articles when the hearer or reader doesn't know which one we are referring to". But here the 'no of people' which I referred to in my original question knew what the speaker was referring to. Then why not 'the' according to the above said reason ?

Comment: @mahmudkoya : Another eg,  A: "The neighbor told that last night you went to watch a movie".                             B :  "No! That's 'a' lie".  Why an indefinite article before the noun 'lie' ?

Comment: @user227275 There 100s of websites with 100s of "rules"  about articles that are incorrect, because they are oversimplified and do not use linguistic terminology. A speaker *can* use an indefinite noun phrase even when the hearer **can** identify the referent: I buy an umbrella; I go home; I see my roommate; I hold the umbrella where my roommate can see it; I say *I bought an umbrella*; my roommate says 'I see that you did'; my roommate knows exactly *which umbrella* I'm talking about, yet I have used an indefinite, but specific, noun phrase

Comment: @Clare : But why books mention that indefinite article cannot be used if the listener/hearer already knows about the noun ?

Comment: @user227275 Which books? I don't know which books you are talking about. But probably for the same reason that many many websites say that: they are trying to teach learners when to use the indefinite article and when to use the definite article; but the things they say, their rules or guidelines or lists are vast oversimplifications; and they do not match or correspond with how the two articles are actually used.

Comment: @Clare -- in your above comment can't we use indefinite article a/an instead of 'the', like this :  "they are trying to teach learners when to use 'an' indefinite article and when to use 'a' definite article.." ?

Comment: @user227275 Now, you are asking about  generic noun phrases. This is a new topic that can't be addressed in comments. But John Lawler explains the three different types of generic noun phrases at http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html Another example is 'This textbook wants to teach you about *the tiger*'. Here, *the tiger* is a generic noun phrase. It does not refer to any actually existing tiger that we can go see at a zoo or in the forest.  It is talking about the prototypical tiger. We usually would not say *a tiger* in this context. But please read the above  website.

Answer (score 1):

While it seems the speaker is referring to himself directly, he is actually doing so indirectly.

He is constructing a category for his audience: *guys like this*, and implying that he is a member of this category.

His use of the indefinite article denotes a representative of that category in the abstract. While "a guy like this" could mean any "guy" matching the particular qualities he is evoking for his audience, from the context we understand he is referring to himself as the particular example. Presumably, there is no other "guy" in the context that he would be referring to.

This all enables him to evoke his unique personality or abilities, etc. for the audience at the same time he refers to himself. He's not just *a guy*, he's *a guy like this*.